# How do servers send messages at a reliable cadence without spinning the CPU

Tags: c++, windows, server, udp, sleep

Lets say I want a server to send a tick every ~8.33ms (120Hz) to all clients.

If the accuracy of sleep() function on Windows is no less than 10ms, how can messages be sent at a 120Hz tickrate without spinning the CPU in a hot loop that's constantly checking if 8.33ms has elapsed since the last tick?

How can the CPU be put to sleep for such a short interval till the next tick?

Comment: Why such a short interval?  That really is unusual.

Comment: @PaulSanders Sorry just changed it to reflect something more realistic, i.e., valorant or csgo faceit server tickrate

Comment: That's still really fast.  What is the purpose of these 'ticks'?  Are they some sort of keepalive?  If so, you would never want to saturate your network with pointless traffic like that.

Comment: @PaulSanders Each tick is an update packet of the game world state like projectiles, other player positions etc.

Comment: The thing you are missing here is the fact that managing ticks is rarely the bottleneck. Most of the time it is the game logic, internet speed, latency, acknowledgement from clients.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  So, a) context like this should have been in the original question, and b) I'm with @aka, try a lower tick rate and see how it looks.  Human brains only go so fast.

Comment: Also, only send anything if you have anything to send, if you see what I mean.

Comment: @akaAbdullahMateen Oh I see. That's actually what I was looking for. I'll look into this raw CPU clock access more. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @akaAbdullahMateen Not sure you're on the right track there.  The issue is how frequently the scheduler reschedules your task (or, perhaps, thread).  Essential reading: https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2020/10/04/windows-timer-resolution-the-great-rule-change/

Comment: @aka What am I looking at?  I know about `__rdtsc` (and it's a compiler intrinsic, so you don't need to resort to assembler to use it), but this is a _scheduler_ issue, not a 'how accurately can I get the time' issue.  Microsoft deprecate `__rdtsc` anyway, OP see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/acquiring-high-resolution-time-stamps.

Comment: One option is the frequent update of all clients for changes in the game scenery. This is what was unimaginable 20 years ago when this was already a subject in distributed battlefield simulation. So there are techniques to compensate such issues. The behavior of a projectile is predictable to some extent. Additional to the current position, you can also provide its velocity (as 3d vector, of course). Thus, the client can extrapolate the flight of that projectile until a new position (with new velocity vector) is received. Just my two cents...

Comment: @PaulSanders Using timeBeginPeriod(1) and sleep_for actually brings the round trip latency down to 0.1-2.0ms and CPU usage is down to 0%! Thanks for the article!

Comment: @Wail3Y OK, good.  Now, don't saturate your network!  That game should work over WiFi, yes?

Comment: In this scenario, updating everything every 8,33ms seems like bad practice, I'm not saying there shouldn't be a delay or be longer, but updating as needed, why update the position of a player who hasn't moved, or things on standby? I don't know how it's working, but having an acceptable minimum for refresh rates is a good thing, but it's not necessary to follow the letter, Windows doesn't guarantee that any form of 'sleep()' will be accurate, the way is to bet on more Cores and Threads. Depending on the data flow, you will have to choose between constant small packets or slower large packets.